# completion block in background thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have a method that does some time extensive data extraction that I'd like executed in the background.  However, I need to return a `UIBezierPath` when the block completes before moving forward.

I'm trying to do this:

```
__block UIBezierPath *blockWavePath = nil;

dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        blockWavePath = [pathGenerator createPathWithAsset:audioAsset andSize:myCell.waveView.bounds.size];
    });
});
```

How can I incorporate the completion check aspect into this?

Comment: that snippet of code.. what is it supposed to do? you don't need the backgroundQueue there at all...

Comment: why don't you just dispatch_sync?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use completion block here, completion blocks are for callback code. Like in your case when you want to do something after some work is completed.

In your case, it should be something like this

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self createPathWithAsset:audioAsset andSize:0 completionBlock:^(UIBezierPath* resultValue){
            blockWavePath = resultValue;
        }];
    });
});
```

Where your `createPathWithAsset` should look something like below

```
-(void) createPathWithAsset: (AVAsset *) asst  andSize : (NSInteger) Size completionBlock: (void (^) (UIBezierPath *)) completionB {


    UIBezierPath *someBezeirPathObject;   //example object
    //Your function implementation goes here
    //.
    //.
    //.


    //When your functionality is achieved, pass the object to completion block
    completionB(someBezeirPathObject);


}
```

For better understanding on completion block, I would suggest [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)
Hope this helps.

Comment: why the background queue?

Comment: You are right, But I suppose its left intentionally, OP might have something to add here. I used the same pattern so that OP could follow the code.

Comment: I'm extracting audio samples from an audio recording, which takes quite a bit of time (depending on the duration of audio file).  Thats my reasoning for doing it in the background.  I understand that doing this on the background won't change the time to extract the samples and render the path by much, but I figure its better to do on a background thread leaving the main thread open for possible UI animation.  Is my logic wrong?

Comment: but can't you make the path in the bg?

Comment: Yes, I plan to make the path in the background.  Is that your question?